# ExpressionEngine 1.7 user & group permissions setting

Tags: members, ee1, admin

Does EE 1.7 have a setting where I can have an arthor and editor? I would like to set roles where an author submits a blog post and an editor gets an email confirmation to edit and publish. Is that possible or is there a plugin I can utilize?

Answer (score 2):

Using the native member group settings, you can definitely create these two groups and set their permissions accordingly. I strongly recommend downloading the EE 1.7 docs in the top right corner of the [EE online User Guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/).

Control Panel Location:  Admin > Members and Groups > Member Groups

Once you create the member groups, edit their permission related to the current weblogs.

There's a section called "Control Panel Administrative Privileges" with a subsection of "Can administrate weblogs and weblog preferences".

That should get you going.